# gradle downloading multiple bom files from log4j-bom with spring-boot plugin for gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, log4j

I was trying to force the version from log4j to 2.17.0 using the spring-boot-plugin for gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}
ext['log4j2.version'] = '2.17.0'
```

but I noticed that it downloaded the version 2.14.1 from log4j-bom.

```
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.17.0/bbd791e9c8c9421e45337c4fe0a10851c086e36c/log4j-api-2.17.0.jar
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.0/e50b82411b9ce9c204c938509f914b2bb887168b/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.0.jar
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.0/d26c64406f2d865c79216a392bbce80f38eaee9f/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.0.pom
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-bom
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-bom/2.14.1/3b35554b11cabd67a3ff93b8a39c7d461aae913d/log4j-bom-2.14.1.pom
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-bom/2.17.0/3d7cdfa8f42cd7626eeca5fa8b1d3c1779c3c0fb/log4j-bom-2.17.0.pom
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j
./modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j/2.17.0/69d2448e9165c6e287181fe0f7fd8d16ea7874ab/log4j-2.17.0.pom
```

Is there any way to force gradle to not download

Comment: Those files are in Gradle’s cache and there may be no connection between the 2.14.1 bom and your current build.

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson, before we run the build, all files from the .cache were deleted.

Comment: I saw that the spring-boot-dependencies https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.5.0 is downloaded because of the plugin and uses log4j-bom 2.14.1. even forcing the version from log4j it keeps downloading the old version.